# Email is being pushed to laravel Queue but doesn't get sent

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to implement a queue to send email in laravel. My .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER = smtp
MAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS = from@gmail.com
MAIL_USERNAME = from
MAIL_PASSWORD = ********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

My config/queue.php

```
'connections' => [
        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],
    ]
```

config/mail.php

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],
]
```

My Job file

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendSampleMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'], ['name' => 'TestUser'], function ($message) {
            $message->to('to@mailinator.com', 'testUserName')->subject('Test Laravel email');
            $message->from('from@gmail.com', 'Test Mail');
        });
    }
}
```

In the controller, I am calling it like

```
$job = new SendSampleMail();
$this->dispatch($job);
```

The mail.blade.php

```
<p>Sending Mail from Laravel.</p>
```

When I run

> php artisan queue:work

The jobs are queued but email fails to be sent.
[image]

I need to fix that issue. Any help would be appreciated.　Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have queue running?

Comment: yes @MarcinOrlowski

Answer (score 0):

As per the [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#database) document, create the `jobs` table in the database.

Run the below two command for the creating the table

```
php artisan queue:table
 
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: did that. jobs are being queued properly. mail is not being sent, they are being moved too failedjobs table

Comment: You can see the reason why the job failed inside the `failed_jobs` table